# Rails3 – refactor redirect call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring

Refactor this:

```
redirect_to "http://#{@school.id}" + '.' + request.domain + request.port_string + '/'
```

That is inside the School controller:

```
def create
    @school = School.new(params[:school]) 

    if @school.save
      redirect_to "http://#{@school.id}" + '.' + request.domain + request.port_string + '/'
    else
      render "new", :layout => nil
    end
end
```

So that it redirect to:

```
subdomain.domain.dom/
```

Routes:

resources :schools
  root :to => "schools#show"

Things tried:

```
redirect_to(:host=>@school.id + '.' + request.domain + request.port_string)
```

Fail because it redirect to http://subdomain.domain.dom/schools

And How do I pass a :notice?

I have this in the view:

```
<% if flash[:notice] -%>
    <div id="info_panel">
    <%= flash[:notice] -%>
    </div>
<% end -%>
```

And this in the controller:

```
flash[:notice] = "School created"
redirect_to(school_base(@school.id))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
redirect_to "http://#{@school.id}.#{request.domain}#{request.port_string}/"
```

If you will use this regularly, you might want to consider adding a method to ApplicationController along the lines of:

```
def url_for_school(school)
  "http://#{school.id}.#{request.domain}#{request.port_string}/"
end
helper_method :url_for_school
```

Comment: Nice. How can I add a :notice?

Comment: If the content on the subdomain is handled by the same app, you should be able to do it normally: `flash[:notice] = "Your notification"`. If it's an entirely separate application, you may want to consider passing it as a query string unless you want to set up cross-app cookies. Ask if you need more info on the latter.

Comment: The app is the same. But the :notice is not showed. You have the current code on the edit.

Comment: Try changing the domain setting on your session store as described here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#highlighter_863164